# No compile errors, warnings in Flash CS6

Tags: flash, actionscript, flash-cs6

(please forgive me, I'm extremely new to flash) When I create SWF file in my flash project in CS6 Pro (by clicking "Test project"), I got no errors, no warnings information whatsoever. SWF is created whether the actionscript code is correct or not (and if code is not correct, SWF don't work properly, so it is affected by the code changes). When I do the same in Flash 8, I got compile errors info in the output tab, but in CS6 there is absolutely nothing...

Comment: What happens if you debug (Ctrl+Alt+Enter)?

Comment: Thanks, it works! I had to open .fla file and then choose 'debug'. Then "Compiler Errors" window appeared next to the "Output" window. I can now just click "Test project" and I have all errors in that window. Please add an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: By the way, how the hell can I publish a project without testing it? I mean I just want to create SWF without any swf preview window popping up. I can't see and I can't find any shortcut for that.

Comment: Ok glad the debugging mode at least works. But though it's better than nothing, normal testing mode is much more convenient for most cases and should work. Maybe it would help if you'd reinstall Flash..

Comment: I also want to say that in the normal testing mode, the errors should be displayed in the 'Compiler errors' tab and not the 'output' tab (but you probably knew that already) :)

Comment: You can publish by clicking File > Publish.. in the menu when you have the .fla file opened. Before publishing you can also choose some extra options, like .jpg quality (should be 100% if you don't want ugly rendered images) and for which Flash Player it should be published for.

Comment: I hope all of this helps, but it's not the actual solution. Reinstalling might be, though, try it.

Comment: Reinstall doesn't change anything, but what do you mean by "normal testing mode"? I've got an errors in 'Compiler Errors' tab when I publish the project, isn't it a 'normal testing mode'? And yes, File->Publish works, but only when when I'm on .fla file. Usually I'm working on .as files and it's annoying, that there is no such an option for the project...

Comment: Ctrl+Enter activates the normal testing/publishing, that's what you meant right? Debugging is a little more advanced and it's convenient not having to use all the time, especially if you're new to Flash.

Comment: Also, I think you're missing an important point here. The .as files are code files that belong to a certain .fla. The .fla is you working file, any .as files are like bricks or cogwheels that provide additional functionality to the .fla (although it's best to use OR just the Flash IDE OR just .as to work with).. But you'll always need a .fla file which calls in a first .as file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to open .fla file and then choose 'debug'. Then "Compiler Errors" window appeared next to the "Output" window. I can now just click "Test project" and I have all errors in that window.

Answer (score -2):

First of all - flash8 is as2 while cs6 is as3. That being said, don't try to blend 2 different things. 2nd of all would be the target platform for your flash - which flash player version are you targeting? The targeted version of the flash player determines what actionscript features you have available to you.

Comment: Flash doesn't equal Actionscript. Flash8 supports AS and AS2, while Flash CS6 supports all three.

Comment: indeed it does not, but then again unless there isn't the same actionscript version (btw AS3 is the 1st option for CS6) the same compile errors he gets in flash8 should be in flash CS6 - those compile errors mr. genious mean that flash CS6 supports things that flash8 doesnt (wait is AS3 supported by Flash CS6 and not by Flash8?).

Comment: What do you mean, the first option? And no Flash 8 doesn't support AS3, because AS3 wasn't in existence at the time Flash 8 was released.

Comment: And btw he already wrote in his post what happens when he tests the movie (that what ctrl+alt+enter stands for) - under CS6 all is ok under flash 8 "I got compile errors info in the output tab".

Comment: "First of all - flash8 is as2 while cs6 is as3" - I also don't get your argument, because CS6 supports AS2 (my project is in AS2). "which flash player version are you targeting" I tested it with every version and it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Ctrl+Enter is testing/rendering the flash and creating the swf file. Crtl+Alt+Enter is debugging. Now stop discussing if you don't know what you're talking about.